# How do I resize a Matlab matrix with a 3rd dimension?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

So I'd like to resize a matrix that is of size 72x144x156 into a 180x360x156 grid. I can try to do it with this command: `resizem(precip,2.5)`. The first two dimensions are latitude and longitude, while the last dimension is time. I don't want time to be resized.

This works if the matrix is of size 72x144. But it doesn't work for size 72x144x156. Is there a way to resize the first two dimensions without resizing the third?

Also, what is the fastest way to do this (preferably without a for loop). If a for loop is necessary, then that's fine.

Comment: Have you tried to apply [`interp3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html) with a grid that doesn't change time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D= %existing matrix
scale=2.5;
E=zeros(size(D,1)*2.5,size(D,2)*2.5,size(D,3))
for depth=1:size(D,3)
  E(:,:,depth)=resizem(D(:,:,depth),scale)
end
```

This should provide the expected output.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Do you know if it's possible to do this in a way that is more computationally efficient than with a for loop?

Comment: I currently don't have ml available, but this should work: `fk=@(depth)(resizem(D(:,:,depth),scale))` `E=arrayfun(fk,(1:size(D,3))`

Because of the relative large steps within the loop, which are already vectorized, I don't expect a relevant improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I hinted in my comment, but could use [interp3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html) like this:

```
outSize = [180 360 156];
[nrows,ncols,ntimes] = size(data);
scales = [nrows ncols ntimes] ./ outSize;

xq = (1:outSize(2))*scales(2) + 0.5 * (1 - scales(2));
yq = (1:outSize(1))*scales(1) + 0.5 * (1 - scales(1));
zq = (1:outSize(3))*scales(3) + 0.5 * (1 - scales(3));
[Xq,Yq,Zq] = meshgrid(xq,yq,zq);
dataLarge = interp3(data,Xq,Yq,Zq);
```

But the problem is simplified if you know you don't want to interpolate between time points, so you can loop as in Daniel R's answer. Although, this answer will not increase the number of time points.

Comment: Oh cool - thanks so much for that answer! Do you know if this method is more time-efficient than the for loop contained in his answer?

Comment: Honestly, I think a for loop is probably no big deal in this case since 180*360 is much larger than 156.  But you'd have to time the two to be sure.  I don't have `resizem` to try his, but you could take mine and do a loop over `interp2` to see.

Answer (score 1):

```
    % s = zeros(72, 144, 156);
    % whos s;
    % news = resize2D(s, 2.5);
    % whos news;

    function [result] = resize2D(input, multiply)
        [d1, d2, d3] = size(input);
        result = zeros(d1*multiply, d2*multiply, d3);
    end
```

Comment: Umm... I think you _might_ be missing a step.

Comment: maybe my understanding of "resize" is not the same as yours... I don't have the "mapping toolbox" of resizem, not sure what is the definition of it.

Comment: The core of the problem is interpolation.  The content of the output matrix should be based on the content of the input, not just `result = zeros(size(input,1)*multiply, size(input,2)*multiply, size(input,3));`  I'm sorry for my comments...