# about using my own code to resize image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

when i try to resize an image by computing the average of 4 pixels to get one pixel, i got a problem, and following are my code, help me please, it's driving me crazy

```
a=imread('c:\black and white.jpg');
[rows,columns,phases]=size(a);
i=1;j=1;k=1;
c=zeros(rows/2,columns/2,phases);
c=uint8(c);
for x=1:2:rows-1;
    for y=1:2:columns;
        for z=1:phases;
        c(i,j,k)=1/4*(a(x,y,z)+a(x,y+1,z)+a(x+1,y,z)+a(x+1,y+1,z));
        k=k+1;
        end
    j=j+1;
    k=1;
    end
    i=i+1;
    j=1;
    k=1;
end
figure, imshow(a)
figure, imshow(c)
```

Comment: Luis has a good answer for the stated problem, but the question is a very specific case of linear interpolation to scale an image by half.  Averaging more pixels with equal weight or attempting other scales will probably not give acceptable results

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without loops, by computing block averages along each column and then alog each row, as follows.

I am assuming your data is an image, i.e. a 2D array. If you have a 3D array with several images piled along the 3rd dimension (as it seems to be in your code), just apply this to each image (that is, for each value of the 3rd index).

Matrix size and block size are arbitrary, as long as block size divides the number of rows and columns of the input matrix `a`.

```
a = rand(100,120); % example data
n = 2; % block size
m = size(a)/n; % assumed to be integer
c = reshape(mean(reshape(a,n,[])),m(1),[]).'; % mean by colummns in groups of n
c = reshape(mean(reshape(c,n,[])),m(2),[]).'; % mean by rows in groups of n
```

Comment: +1. But pretty please to the OP don't expect good results for larger block sizes.  You almost certainly don't want an equal weight average of n^2 neighboring pixels to downsize an image. I like Luis' answer for elegance in solving the problem as stated, but to the OP: please consider doing proper interpolation by computing the correct weights so you understand how this works in general. Computing weights and pixel centers is non-trivial for any scale if you want avoid phase shift. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19528632/2778484) for how to do it in correctly 3D (or `imresize`!).

Comment: Thank you,guys,I really appreciate your work, however, I still really want to know what's wrong in my code,because the requirement of professor is using my own code.here are two pictures before and after resize http://imageshack.us/a/img542/9521/bnn5.jpg    http://imageshack.us/a/img542/9521/bnn5.jpg    and I have another question, after I try your code, the picture matrix is in double type, and sometimes it doesnt work,and you need to change it to uint8, am I correct?  And for the next guy, in your code, I don't know what's xq = (1:outSize(2))*scales(2) + 0.5 * (1 - scales(2)); means?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your question is as simple as this, assuming you have a image called `myImage`:

First make sure the number of pixels in each direction is even

```
myImage = myImage(1:fix(end/2)*2,1:fix(end/2)*2)
```

Then take the average of each 4 pixels

```
(myImage(1:2:end,1:2:end)+myImage(2:2:end,1:2:end)+ ...
myImage(1:2:end,2:2:end)+myImage(2:2:end,2:2:end))/4
```

Note that this assumes that you don't mind losing the last row or column of pixels, otherwise you need to do something smarter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your code is better than me, however after I try your code the result is as same as mine,here is two links of picture, one is original, the other is after resize. the size changed as well as the color, and I cant figure out why.http://imageshack.us/a/img542/9521/bnn5.jpg       http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/2379/tb7w.jpg